# Create a jscolor by click event, or by loading a sample.html that contains jscolor into a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jscolor

I am trying to create a color picker using jscolor by clicking on a div, something like this doesn't work.

```
<div id='aa'>make anohter</div>
<div id='bb'></div>
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/jscolor/jscolor.js"></script> 
<script>
$( "#aa" ).click(function() {
    document.getElementById("bb").innerHTML = "<input class='color'>";
});
</script>
```

I creates a input in that div, but not a jscolor.
I originally wanted to use .load('sample.html') on a div, the sample.html has a color picker, but it didn't work too. 
I tried so many stuff, only this seem to work:

```
$('#somediv').click(function(){
$('#colorpicker').appendTo( "#newplace" )};
```

but then it will remove the #colorpicker, which will make my click work only one time. I tried to use clone methods, didn't work.
 Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#aa").click(function() {
  document.getElementById("bb").innerHTML = "<input class='color'>";
  jscolor.installByClassName('color');
});
```

```css
#aa {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jscolor/2.0.4/jscolor.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='aa'>Show JS color pickr</div>
<div id='bb'></div>
```